# Beginner's Guide to Derandomization

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, derandomization, randomized-algorithms

I found the book [Pairwise Independence and Derandomization](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1933019220) on the subject, but it's more research-oriented than tutorial oriented.

I'm new to the subject of "Derandomization," and as such, I wanted to know which reference to start from?

I prefer one that discusses literature and history, as well as the technical details.

Comment: Arora and Barak's textbook on computational complexity covers derandomization fairly well. Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look. I don't have anything else in my mind. Just to read and understand some papers, I need to understand derandomization first.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The notes from Salil Vadhan's class, ["Pseudorandomness"](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/cs225/), are excellent for this purpose.  He is writing a textbook based on these.  The draft version of the book is available [online](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/pseudorandomness/).

Comment: nice link. Looking forward to the book when it comes out

Comment: Yes, really appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

I really like [Pseudorandom Generators: A Primer](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/prg-primer.html) by Oded Goldreich. I think it's very well written and probably at the level you want. (Not very research oriented, but still has technical details.)

Comment: It's been published as a [book](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0821851926/?tag=brel-20) in 2010.